# Microsoft Word: Remove Popup Window, You can only view this document. You do not have permissions to edit it

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

When I open a read-only document in Word, I see window at top right-hand side  saying "Viewing. You can only view this document. You do not have permissions to edit it." I don't need this redundant pop up window every time I open a document. How do I disable the Pop out Window in Word?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to "File" > "Options".
2. In the left menu, go to "Trust Center" and then click on the button "Trust Center Settings...".
   [image]
3. Again in the left window click on "Protected View" and uncheck the boxes which enable the protected view. With that, usually all yellow bars and pop-ups are gone.
   [image]